# How to fetch captured images from storage directory using HTML 5 Image capture in Android?

Tags: javascript, html

I m creating mobile web application using html5,javascript,jquery,jquery mobile.I m using [Media Capture using HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html-media-capture-20130509/) to capture images inside the mobile web application.Using this api i m taking images.It is saving in the storage directory //sdcard/DCIM/browser-photos/image1.jpg. Shall i change the image saving path?Shall i access the path?Please suggest if it possible Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use an <input type=file> to grab sdcard files.

Comment: @dandavis is there any way to access the path programmatically without using <input type=file>

Comment: no, the browser javascript doesn't even know the path that the browser/device/user chooses to place the files. you can probably capture the images to js instead of a file, then you can dump the contents from js into a file using <a download>

Comment: @dandavis What is our requirement is we will take some 10 images and will store in a place.then we will navigate to other pages.From there we have to sync the 10 images to server?Is that possible that js file will be stable? can you explain in deep?

Comment: depending on the size of the images, you can use localStorage or indexedDB to save the image data as dataURLs, allowing the local device to load the images on subsequent page visits without a server or user action.

Comment: @dandavis We have tried with localstorage and websql but memory limit is the hurdle for storing images.That is what i am trying with some different storage place

Comment: you probably have to use smaller images at this point...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44863/discussion-between-kanna-and-dandavis)